# How to access combobox selected value inside in Listview in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

How to get selected value of combobox present inside a listview.

Here is my code:

`cbPriority` is name of my combobox.

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-1094,0,2,24" RenderTransformOrigin="0.621,0.497" MinHeight="750" MinWidth="650">
    <ListView Name="lvShowSearching" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}" MinHeight="300" MinWidth="400" RenderTransformOrigin="2.25,4" Margin="1129,213,26,187" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FF90A1CD" Background="White" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding KeywordID}">
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Visibility="Hidden"></StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Publication" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PublicationName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Total Records" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TotalRecords}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Records Imported" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TotalRecordsImported}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Priority" Width="100">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Name="cbPriority" Width="80" Height="22">
                                <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">1</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>4</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>5</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>6</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>7</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>8</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>9</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>10</ComboBoxItem>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button Content="Add Filter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1761,113,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Click="Filter_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new property in your view model along with other properties eg KeywordID, PublicationName, TotalRecords, Status etc.

example

```
    public object SelectedComboItem { get; set; }
```

and bind it to the ComboBox selecteditem

```
    <ComboBox Name="cbPriority" Width="80" Height="22" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboItem}">
```

or a better name would be

```
    public object SelectedPriority { get; set; }
```

and binding

```
    <ComboBox Name="cbPriority" Width="80" Height="22" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPriority}">
```

if you want a int property you may perhaps go for

```
public int SelectedPriority { get; set; }

<ComboBox Name="cbPriority"
          Width="80"
          Height="22"
          xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPriority,FallbackValue=1}">
    <sys:Int32 >1</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32>3</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32>4</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32>5</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32>6</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32>7</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32>8</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32>9</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32>10</sys:Int32>
</ComboBox>
```

**Bind combobox to value collection**

to bind to a collection instead of static values in xaml

create a property in the same class as of property SelectedPriority and initialize it accordingly

example

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Priorities { get; set; }
```

bind to combo box as

```
<ComboBox Name="cbPriority"
          Width="80"
          Height="22"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPriority,FallbackValue=1}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Priorities}" >
```

or if you want to bind combo box to list of values which are common for all, create a static property for the same

eg

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class MyClass
    {
        static MyClass()
        {
            Priorities = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> Priorities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

bind it this way

```
<ComboBox Name="cbPriority"
          Width="80"
          Height="22"
          xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPriority,FallbackValue=1}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static l:MyClass.Priorities}}" >
```

I added namespace in the example to show the correct binding using `x:Static` you may choose to have your own namespace

Comment: If I need to bind  the comobobox with a list instead of static values then how it can I bind and access the same ?

Comment: Getting an error : MyClass doesnot exists in the namespace
I used this way 

namespace Searching
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        static MyClass()
        {
            Priorities = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> Priorities { get; set; }
    }

       public partial class ImportedKeywords : Window
    {
        CommonMethods objCommon = new CommonMethods();
        public ImportedKeywords()
        {
            MyClass.Priorities = MyClass.Priorities;

            InitializeComponent();
            BindList();
        }

Comment: `MyClass.Priorities = MyClass.Priorities;` may not be necessary. do post the combobox xaml too. typically it should be `xmlns:l="clr-namespace:Searching" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static l:MyClass.Priorities}}"`

Answer (score 0):

I 'solved' my issue by using the WPF Toolkit grid (http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117) and a series of selected items, which is probably a cleaner solution anyway. Doesn't explain the behavior of the GridView, which is to me unusual